# DataFrame each column miltiply param then sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe which columns is `['a','b','c']` and a Series `param` contain three values which is params of Dataframe. The `param.index` is `['a','b','c']`. I want to realize `df['a'] * param['a'] + df['b'] * param['b'] + df['c'] * param['c']`. Because there are too many columns and params in my code. So is there any concise and elegant code can realize this?

Comment: Please refer to this link on how to ask a question that will get you better responses & good answers https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Can you post some portion of dataframe representing the input & also expected output

Comment: The portion of dataframe is nothing to do with this so you can ignore it or randomly generate one.

Comment: did you try to use `for`-loop ? ie. `for name in ['a','b','c']: result += df[name] * param[name]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, this is what you need.

```
Input dataframe df
    a   b   c
0   1   1   1
1   2   2   2
2   3   3   3
3   4   4   4
4   5   5   5
```

series `a=[2,20,200]`

**Solution**

```
b=df.columns
df1=df[b]*a
```

**Output df1**

```
    a   b   c
0   2   20  200
1   4   40  400
2   6   60  600
3   8   80  800
4   10  100     1000
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `df * param.to_list()` is good.

Answer (score 1):

`df*param` is enough, it will auto determine according to the index.

You can change series indexes to ['b','c','a'] for testing